# Adding a string to the front of array loop?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, loops, append

```
#!/bin/bash
#OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\r'
    fortune_lines=($(fortune | fold -w 90))

    #Screen_Session=$"{mainscreen}"
        Screen_Session=`screen -ls|grep "\."|grep "("|awk '{print $1}'`
    Screen_OneLiner=$(screen -p 0 -S ${Screen_Session} -X stuff "`printf "${fortune_lines[@]}\r"`")
#IFS=$OLDIFS;
    for var in "${Screen_OneLiner[@]}"
      do
         echo    "${var}"
    done
```

ok this script works (sorta). I need to at the string "say " to front of the entire array index.  Currently I can only get it to print out "say " to the first line.

Comment: Yes and No. Yes it is a built in command in osx in '/usr/bin/say'. Turns text to speak. But I would just need to use 'say ' as a string. 'say ' in for my usage is just command in java vm. Its a minecraft server and you need to prefix all comments by the server with 'say '

Comment: Show the current output and desired output (I don't have those commands on my Cygwin session).

Comment: I am not at home at the moment but essentially

Comment: I am not at home at the moment but essentially, the output looks like `say line 0 of the array` then `all the rest of the array loops without say on the front` So I would like it to say `say on the front of each loop of the array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need not complicate things with contraptions like arrays - we can let good old `sed` do the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
fortune_lines=$(fortune | fold -w 90 | sed 's/^/say /')
Screen_Session=`screen -ls|grep "\."|grep "("|awk '{print $1}'`
screen -p 0 -S $Screen_Session -X stuff "$fortune_lines"
```